# pygtk3 checking does signal exist

Tags: pygtk

how can I learn this before connecting anything.

example

```
does_signal_exist(widget, signal):
    pass

button = Gtk.Button()

does_signal_exist(button, "clicked") # returns True
does_signal_exist(button, "hello") # returns False
does_signal_exist(button, "unboxed") # returns False
does_signal_exist(button, "button-press-event") # returns True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def does_signal_exist(gtkWidgetObj, sigTag):
    try:
        gtkWidgetObj.emit(sigTag)
        return True
    except:
        return "unknown signal name" not in format_exc():
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a wondrous tool called ['manual'](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/) or ['reference'](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/). Look for the Gtk-3.0 manual, and click on [Classes](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes.html), and look for [Gtk.Button](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Button.html). Look for [Signals](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Button.html#signals). If not there you can do the same for the signals inherited from previous Objects.

Using `help(button` or even `help(Gtk.Button)` (inside Python3, either in interactive or in a program), you have access to all methods, and lots of other information about the class and the instance.

Using the manual mentioned above, check out the GiRepository module - these are functions which you can use to look inside Gtk, its classes and properties.

And you can just check if it works: Use `try:/except:` to check if you can actually connect to the signal/event you are interested in.